# Dúvida no IF - PHP

Tags: php

Estou com um dúvida na condição que estou querendo colocar no meu sistema.
Se o `ID` do dono do anúncio for igual ao da sessão aparecerá um botão de "aceitar negociação", se não, aparece o botão de "Produto a caminho". Ao testar só fica aparecendo o botão de "Aceitar negociação".

Segue o código:

```
<?php
$id_usuario_anuncio = $_GET["ID_usuario"];
$id_usuario_sessao = $_SESSION["id"];
if($id_usuario_anuncio == $id_usuario_sessao)
{
   echo '<form method="post" action="">
   <input type="hidden" name="ATIVAR/EXCLUIR" value="<?php echo $_GET["ID"]; ?>">
   <div class="panel-footer">
   <button type="submit" name="ativar" id="ativar" value="ATIVAR"class="botao_cardapio">Aceitar negocição</button> 
   </div>
   </form>';
}
else
{
   echo '<form method="post" action="">
   <input type="hidden" name="ATIVAR/EXCLUIR" value="<?php echo $_GET["ID"]; ?>">
   <div class="panel-footer">
   <button type="submit" name="excluir" id="excluir" value="EXCLUIR"class="botao_cardapio">Produto a caminho</button> 
   </div>
   </form>';
}
?>
```

Comment: (Fiz um comentário mas apaguei pq não vinha ao caso)... Se está entrando sempre na primeira condição, é porque os valores são iguais. Seu problema está vindo de outro lugar. A SESSION pode estar vazia e o $_GET também.

Answer (score 1):

O seu problema é com a sintaxe que está totalmente incorreta. Veja exemplos na linha 7 e na linha 16. Você abriu tag `PHP` dentro de uma tag `PHP`. Então a resolução é simples:

```
<?php
$id_usuario_anuncio = $_GET["ID_usuario"];
$id_usuario_sessao = $_SESSION["id"];


if($id_usuario_anuncio == $id_usuario_sessao)
    {
    echo '<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="ATIVAR/EXCLUIR" value="'.$_GET["ID"].'">
    <div class="panel-footer">
    <button type="submit" name="ativar" id="ativar" value="ATIVAR" class="botao_cardapio">Aceitar negocição</button> 
    </div>
    </form>';
    }
else
    {
    echo '<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="ATIVAR/EXCLUIR" value="'.$_GET["ID"].'>
    <div class="panel-footer">
    <button type="submit" name="excluir" id="excluir" value="EXCLUIR" class="botao_cardapio">Produto a caminho</button> 
    </div>
    </form>';
    }
?>
```

Mas se me permite, eu criei um sistema um pouco mais simples pra que você não dobre o tamanho do seu arquivo (O que implica na largura de banda quando for hospedar):

```
<?php
$ua = $_GET["ID_usuario"];
$us = $_SESSION["id"];

    if ($ua == $us) {
        $text  = "Aceitar negociação";
        $name_id = "ativar";
    } else {
        $text  = "Produto a caminho";
        $name_id = "excluir";
    }
    $value = strtoupper($name_id); // retorna "ACEITAR"

?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="ATIVAR/EXCLUIR" value="<?php echo $_GET['ID'] ?>">
    <div class="panel-footer">
    <button type="submit" name="<?php echo $name_id ?>" id="<?php echo $name_id ?>" value="<?php echo $value ?>" class="botao_cardapio"><?php echo $text ?></button> 
    </div>
</form>
```